# ExpatError: not well-formed (invalid token) in rtcclient

Tags: python, python-2.7, rtc

As per [doc](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/rtcclient), I am trying to extract workitems from RTC tool using `rtcclient` python package.

I am using the following code snippet :

```
from rtcclient.utils import setup_basic_logging
from rtcclient import RTCClient
setup_basic_logging()
user = "prabhakar_gadupudi"
url = "https://jazz.net/jazz/"
passwd = "password@123"
proxies = {
        'http': 'http://<usrname>:<passowrd>@<ip>:<port>',
        'https': 'https://<usrname>:<passowrd>@<ip>:<port>',
    }
myclient = RTCClient(url, user, passwd, proxies=proxies)
print myclient

returned_properties = "dc:title,dc:identifier,rtc_cm:state,rtc_cm:ownedBy"
workitems_list = myclient.getWorkitems(projectarea_id=None, projectarea_name=None, returned_properties=returned_properties)
print workitems_list
```

While executing this I am getting following error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\rtcclient\client.py", line 959, in getWorkitems
    pa_ids = self.getProjectAreaIDs(projectarea_name)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\rtcclient\client.py", line 294, in getProjectAreaIDs
    projectareas = self.getProjectAreas(archived=archived)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\rtcclient\client.py", line 158, in getProjectAreas
    returned_properties=returned_properties)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\rtcclient\client.py", line 212, in _getProjectAreas
    filter_rule=filter_rule)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\rtcclient\client.py", line 1357, in _get_paged_resources
    raw_data = xmltodict.parse(resp.content)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\xmltodict.py", line 330, in parse
    parser.Parse(xml_input, True)
ExpatError: not well-formed (invalid token): line 21, column 77
```

Can someone help me on this?

Comment: check if you can get a single workitem. First Debug if you are getting the values of myclient and returned_properties properly

Comment: there may be the token expiring issue or check with only one returned property"dc:title"